# LeftJoin Alias Creation issue without relationship with another table Doctrine Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, left-join

> I am facing issue regarding Left join query in doctrine while table
>   have no relation with other tables so when I am doing join than
>   getting 500 internal server error but when I am doing with other 2
>   tables which have relation than working.I have tried to create alias
>   with different way like Leftjoin('BundleName:Entity', 'alias') but not
>   working.I have 5 tables as below and there relation are defined as
>   below.

client:
    id - Primary key
    client fname
    client lname

```
site:    
id - Primary key
site name
site details    

report:    
id - Primary key
site_id - Foreign key of site table
client_id - Foreign key of client table
title
description

report_call_out    
id- Foreign key of Report table
call title
call detail

report_works    
id- Foreign key of Report table
works title
works detail

These are the relationship in my database so I am getting all list from Report table when I am doing Left Join with other table like report_call_out and report_works which has no relationship from report table than I am getting internal server error but without adding both table in Join, Rest of 2 tables(Client and site) join working fine.

Can you please guide me that where I am having issue.?

I am using below code to populate all list of records.   

  $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
                       ->leftJoin('r.client', 'c')
                       ->leftJoin('r.site', 's');
```

After this code I printed query in DQL format using this code (echo $qb->getQuery()->getDQL();) and It's not showing me any left join with report_call_out table and report_works table.

But When I printed query in SQL format using this code($qb->getQuery()->getSQL();) than it will be automatically Left Join added in query with both tables report_call_out and report_works.

Comment: Where do you call `$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')` exactly? Furthermore, "500 Internal Server Error" is not a very detailed information. I assume an exception is thrown somewhere. Please provide some more details.

Comment: @W0rma, I am calling $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r') that from ReportRepository file. I want use report_call_out table fields for filter result

Comment: Please provie more details about the exception which was thrown. "500 Internal Server Error" is not very helpful

Comment: When i am adding leftJoin for report_call_out than getting 500 error

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
                       ->leftJoin('r.client', 'c')
                       ->leftJoin('AcmeReportBundle:report_call_out', 'rc','WITH','r.id = rc.id')
                       ->leftJoin('r.site', 's');
```

Use "WITH" for join external table . report_id is FK

Comment: I have added above code After that I am doing $qb->getQuery()->getResult() than getting 500 internal server error. In ReportCallOut.php entity don't have id property defined.

Comment: You can run in app_dev.php environment so it's showing exact error

Comment: SELECT r FROM AcmeBundle\Entity\Report r LEFT JOIN r.client c LEFT JOIN AcmeBundle:report_call_out rc WITH r.id = rc.id LEFT JOIN r.site s WHERE  s.contractNumber LIKE :site_id  ORDER BY r.id desc

here is query that run in DQL format

Comment: Can you please share your report_call_out entity path and entity name and also this table field list

Comment: Already mentioned field list... Entity path is same and entity name is Report

Comment: i means where is located your report_call_out entity not report and it's entity name. For ex. AcmeReportBundle:<entity>.

Comment: Inside entity folder  (AcmeReportBundle/Entity/ReportCallOut.php). 

In this file, It's like this in comment.

* @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="reports_call_out")

Comment: Please try this
->leftJoin('AcmeReportBundle:ReportCallOut', 'rc','WITH','r.id = rc.id')

Comment: Please clear cache and try this and also check your database relation is valid or not using php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146511/discussion-between-bhavik-and-tester).